# OpenCSV newbie: how to get content from specific cells

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

I'm trying to get whatever is under a specific header and turn that into a String. I want my code to recognize a header and get the content right under it. Basically get info in a specific cell. What am I doing wrong? I know how to do this by calling specific columns, but now I want to know how to do it by making the code recognize a specific header.

Edit: I updated my code, but still nothing is changed... Help?

```
ImageAnnotation PeserAnnotation1 = new ImageAnnotation ();
    String csvFilename = "C:/Users/Daniela/Documents/ISPY/205_4493_MR1_ACRIN_6657/E25008/peser_data.csv"; //Insert file name and location
    CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFilename));
    String [] headerLine = csvReader.readNext();

    //start imageannotation info
    for (int i = 0; i < headerLine.length; i++){
            if (headerLine[i].equals("PRIMARY_ID")) //customize name
            {
                CSVReader csvreader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFilename), ',', '\'', 1);
                String [] nextLine = csvreader.readNext();
                PeserAnnotation1.setPRIMARY_ID(nextLine[i]); 
            }
            else
            {
                PeserAnnotation1.setPRIMARY_ID(""); 
            }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < headerLine.length; i++){    
            if (headerLine[i].equals("ISPY_ID")) //customize name
            {
                CSVReader csvreader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFilename), ',', '\'', 1);
                String [] nextLine = csvreader.readNext();
                PeserAnnotation1.setISPY_ID(nextLine[i]); 
            }
        else
            {
                PeserAnnotation1.setISPY_ID("");
            }
    }
```

The CSV File:

> PRIMARY_ID,ISPY_ID, DATE,      PE_FTV
>     205,       1207,    20050819,  8.7508545

Both my code and the CSV file are just samples of the real thing. 
Currently the code just skips over the "if" and goes straight to the "else".

Comment: don't make a new CsvReader in the for loops, reuse the already open csvReader that you got the header line from...

Comment: i did that originally to skip the first row with the headers so the code would grab whatever was in the following rows. i removed the Csvreader in the loops, but there seems to be no difference in the outcome...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the problem, I inserted a `break` after the `if` statement. Without it, the code would enter the loop again, enter the `else` clause, and replace the string from the `if` statement with the stuff in the `else`.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `==` to compare Strings. Use `equals()` instead. `==` tests if two expressions reference the exact same object. Not if two strings contain the same characters.

Comment: Then you have other bugs. Edit your question and paste your updated code, after the changes suggested in the comments and in my answer. Show example input, the output you desire, and the ourput you get.

Answer (score 0):

Your code in fact goes inside the `if` condition.

```
for (int i = 0; i < headerLine.length; i++){
            if (headerLine[i].equals("PRIMARY_ID")) //customize name
            {
                System.out.println("inside PRIMARY_ID IF");
                CSVReader csvreader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFilename), ',', '\'', 1);
                String [] nextLine = csvreader.readNext();

            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("inside PRIMARY_ID ELSE");
            }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < headerLine.length; i++){    
            if (headerLine[i].equals("ISPY_ID")) //customize name
            {
                System.out.println("inside ISPY_ID IF");
                CSVReader csvreader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFilename), ',', '\'', 1);
                String [] nextLine = csvreader.readNext();

            }
        else
            {
            System.out.println("inside ISPY_ID ELSE");
            }
    }
```

gives me the following output

```
inside PRIMARY_ID IF
inside PRIMARY_ID ELSE
inside PRIMARY_ID ELSE
inside PRIMARY_ID ELSE
inside ISPY_ID ELSE
inside ISPY_ID IF
inside ISPY_ID ELSE
inside ISPY_ID ELSE
```